# open paypal checkout modal after backend response success

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have one form if user enter his details on his form and submit form, after submit form it stores to database and after successfully store users data in database only then i have to open paypal checkout modal otherwise not.

this is paypal

```
paypal.Button.render({

  env: 'sandbox',
  client: {
    sandbox: ''
    // production: 'demo_production_client_id'
  },

  locale: 'en_US',
  style: {

    layout: 'horizontal',
    size: 'small',
    color:  'blue',
    shape:  'pill',
    label: 'checkout',
    height: 40,
    tagline: 'false'
  },

  commit: true,

  payment: (data, actions) => { 
      return actions.payment.create({
        transactions: [{
          amount: {
            total: '1',
            currency: 'USD'
          }
        }]
      });
  },
  
  onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute()
    .then(function() {  
      window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
    });
  }
 }, this.paypalRef.nativeElement);
```

this is submit form api call

```
  submit(){
  const data={
   url: this.URL,
   email:this.email
 }
 this.home.websiteScratching(data)
 .subscribe(res=>{

 },err=>{
   console.log(err);
 })
}


after submit success response i want to go for paypal checkout process how to do it.. i am stuck.
```

Comment: Whatkind error showing?

Comment: i have no idea how to do it, if you know please tell me, i just have that code

Answer (score 0):

In short you have to create new component and use dialogRef.
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

```
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SuccessPaymentPaypalComponent, {
    disableClose: true,
    data: { PaypaplRetunrnTrasactionId: this.params.Paypalid }
 })
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
 });
```